# FlatList Touchable opacity not working on Android

Tags: react-native

I have FlatList data on top of that i want to press each data to open the detail view. Its working with iOS but not with Android.

```
_renderItem = ({item,index}) => { 
        var allcat = [];
        for(let itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < item.data.length; itemIndex++) {
        allcat.push(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('FlavoursDetails',{itemId: item.data[itemIndex].itemid})}>
            <Text style={styles.SectionListItemStyle}>{item.data[itemIndex].itemname}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
        }
        return (     
          <ScrollView style={{
          flex:1, width:'100%',
          shadowRadius: 4.65,elevation: 10,  borderWidth:1, borderColor:'#ccc', margin:0, padding:0, borderRadius:10,marginTop:30, backgroundColor:'#fff', }}>
           <Text style={styles.SectionHeaderStyle}>{item.title}</Text>
           <TouchableOpacity>
               {allcat}
           </TouchableOpacity>
            </ScrollView>
        )
     }
```

Comment: Strange, I don't if it matters. I changed TouchableOpactiy to TouchableHighlight for android and keep  TouchableOpactiy as it is for ios. And it's working.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you are not using the TouchableOpacity from react-native-gesture-handler instead of react-native.

Answer (score 0):

only one TouchableOpacity is enough:

```
return (     
     <ScrollView style={{flex:1, width:'100%', shadowRadius: 4.65,elevation: 10,  borderWidth:1, borderColor:'#ccc', margin:0, padding:0, borderRadius:10,marginTop:30, backgroundColor:'#fff', }}>
         <Text style={styles.SectionHeaderStyle}>{item.title}</Text>
         {allcat}
     </ScrollView>
);
```

Comment: I want function to handle the onPress(). i.e I have array of arrays and i want inner array to handle onPress().